# Wait in suspend fun until flow returns

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a suspend function 'callbackFromSdkA' that gets called from a dependecy called SDK "A". The function should return a certain value called 'finalResult'. In the suspend function I need to call SDK "B" that will show its own screens and needs some user input. As soon as SDK "B" is done I get a callback with the result 'sdkBCallback'. With this result I can create finalResult that I must return from 'callbackFromSdkA'.

My problem is that i don't know how to wait in the function until finalResult is initialized. In rx I would do this with a BehaviourSubject and call firstOrError.await(). My constraint is to use flow without rx.

```
private val _sdkBResultFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val sdkBResult: SharedFlow<Int> = _sdkBResultFlow

private lateinit var finalResult: FinalReturnValue

override suspend fun callbackFromSdkA(initValue: Int): FinalReturnValue {
    val callbackHandlerForSdkB = this
    sdkB.showSdkBWithScreensAndGetCallback(callBackHandler, initValue)

    sdkBresult.collect { sdkBResult ->
        finalResult = createFinalResult(sdkBResult)
    }

    // I somehow have to wait here until finalResult is initialized

    return finalResult
}

override fun sdkBCallback(sdkBResult: Int) {
    _sdkBResultFlow.emit(it)
}
```

Comment: I think you might look at `callbackFlow` instead of `MutableSharedFlow`. As `MutableSharedFlow` never completes, it becomes difficult to await for sdk b result. However, if you use callbackFlow instead, you can sync its completion upon sdk b callback call. If there's a single value to get back from B, there even might be another simpler solution based on mutex or another Kotlinx primitive.